# MySQL trigger capability

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've never implemented a trigger in MySQL but I now have a potential use for one and I'd like to know if it's possible.

In a nutshell, if data (a whole number) in a column in one table (table #1) is updated I need for multiple records which contain this data (the whole number) in a different table (table #2) to be updated as well, but only in the records which match the DATE of the record in the first table (table #1). No relationship (i.e. key) exists between these two tables because the data (the whole number) is not unique to either table.

Would a trigger be the best solution for this?

Comment: *Would a trig...?* Why not? What is your doubt about it?

Comment: my doubt stems from the lack of concrete examples I've been able to find similar to mine, and my unfamiliarity with TRIGGER syntax. However, the answer provided below helps me better understand how to structure a trigger in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, this should be the trigger that you are looking for:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER tbl1_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl1
FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (NEW.num <=> OLD.num) THEN 
  UPDATE tbl2 SET tbl2.num = NEW.num, updated='Y'
  WHERE tbl2.num = OLD.num AND tbl2.dt = NEW.dt;
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Please see an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387e77/1).

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, I understand the DELIMITER aspect of the trigger. And you're saying I should use BEFORE UPDATE rather than ON UPDATE. So, in the rest of the syntax I should substitute my field and table names accordingly, correct?

Comment: @Jim yes, you should only change field and table names accordingly. I'm not too sure how you want to perform the update, this trigger updates num field of tbl2 whenever the num field of tbl1 is updated, and it also sets a column updated='Y'. I hope the logic is correct.

Comment: Okay, great. The only thing I'm still confused about is how the date is being used. I think in my case the syntax would need to be tweaked so that the update occurs for every record in table2 that matches the date of the one record in table1. Right now I don't see anything in this syntax that defines the date of the record in table1, unless I'm missing something. Or is it being defined in NEW.dt?

Comment: HAHA! It worked perfectly!!! Thank you SO much for the help, fthiella! I never would have figured this out on my own. Just this one example has cleared up quite a bit of confusion I had about the syntax of triggers. EXCELLENT!

Comment: @jim you're welcome... thanks :) yes NEW.dt is the NEW value for the column dt, while OLD.dt is the old value of the column, before the update. You need to see which one fits best, depending on the logic of your trigger, eg. if you only update num both OLD.dt and NEW.dt would be the same, but if you update both (num, dt) which records of tbl2 you want to match, the ones that match OLD.dt or NEW.dt?

Comment: Yes, now that I understand the syntax better, I can confess much of my confusion has surrounded how NEW and OLD descriptors are used in triggers. In my mind I was under the impression that "NEW.dt" should instead be labeled as "tbl1.dt". My logic was interfering with my comprehension.